# Getting from Heathrow terminal 2 to the terminal 5 long stay car park

Tags: automobiles, lhr

I'm flying out from Heathrow terminal 5, but returning to terminal 2 (different airlines for outward and return due to available times of flights).

I plan to park in the long stay car park for terminal 5.

When I arrive back in terminal 2, is there a shuttle bus that will get me directly to the T5 long-stay car park?  E.g., is there a bus service that does a "circular" service stopping at all the various car parks on the perimeter road?

Or should I use the shuttle train to go from T2 to T5, and then just get the regular car park bus from there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you arrive at T2 then you can take the shuttle bus to the T2 and T3 business car park which is adjacent to the T5 long stay. As far as my experience there is no check on the car park shuttles of whether you really want that car park so this should work.

Of course you could always take the shuttle train as you say and then get the shuttle from T5 but that does seem a bit indirect.